# Golang os.Create path with nested directories

Tags: go, operating-system

As mentioned in GoDocs, `os.Create()` creates a file in specific path.

```golang
os.Create("fonts/foo/font.eot")
```

But when `fonts` or `foo` doesn't exists, it returns `panic: open fonts/foo/font.eot: The system cannot find the path specified.`
So i used `os.MkdirAll()` to create nested directory. But there are many other problems with this function.

```golang
path := "fonts/foo/font.eot"
// this line create a directory named (font.eot) !
os.MkdirAll(path, os.ModePerm)
```

Is there any better way to create a file in nested directories?

Comment: That's the proper way to do such things - on the system level those map to `mkdir` and `open` system calls. What "many other problems" are you referring to?

Comment: It is `os.MkdirAll("fonts/foo", 0770); os.Create("fonts/foo/font.eot")` Dead simple and totaly obvious.

Comment: @Volker: most programs should probably use mode `0777` rather than `0770` here. File creation generally should use mode `0666`. These allow the user's umask to take away group and/or other write permissions if desired, or even more permissions (resulting in modes like 0750 or 0700 for a directory) if desired. (I've seen this advice to use 0770 elsewhere, but am not sure where it originates.)

Comment: @torek Neither the filepaths nor the modes are fixed and need adoption to your particular use case. There is no single correct value.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The standard way is something like this:

```
func create(p string) (*os.File, error) {
    if err := os.MkdirAll(filepath.Dir(p), 0770); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return os.Create(p)
}
```

A few notes:

- os.Create does not panic as stated in the question.
- Create a directory from the directory part of the file path, not the full path.

Comment: Second note is important!